# Why are spin coated polymer solar cells more efficient?

Tags: solid-state-physics, renewable-energy, solar-cells

Reading papers on polymer solar cells (PSC from now on), it is seen that many different coating techniques are used in order to coat polymer films on substrates. It is also seen that spin coated devices are more efficient than PSC produced using exactly the same materials, but using a different coating technique (such as ESD or H-dipping). Is this related to some particular feature of spin coating? Are spin coated films more uniform, so PSC produces with this method seem to be more efficient?

Comment: There is not such a rule. If you are still interested I can give you further details .

Comment: Well if we are limited to polymer orgajic

Comment: Well if we are limited to polymer organic solar cells might be true but still it is likely by a nice combo of factors.